# Jquery pulsate from different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pulsate from white to another color but i'm not sure how to add color to this code

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#white36").click(function () {
          $('#book').effect("pulsate", { times:3000 }, 500);
    });
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: I view your profile and You ask 3 times about the same problem. I flaged this question.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need this plugin to animate colors with jquery (its not there be default):
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

then you can do something like:

```
var pulsateInterval = null, i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#white36').click(function() {
      // set interval to pulsate every 1500ms
      pulsateInterval = setInterval(function(){
          // animate back and forth
          $('#book').animate({
             background-color: 'red',
          }, 500).animate({
             background-color: 'white',
          }, 500);
          i++;
          // stop at 3000 pulsations
          if(i == 3000){
              clearInterval(pulsateInterval);
          }
      }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pulsate only changes de opacity of an element, not the color. You can put an element with white background below your element to get what you want.

Like:
`<div style="background:#ffffff;"><div id="my_elem" style="#006600"></div></div>`

Comment: i really want it to pulsate from white to red so i'm trying to figure out if theres a way to use ".animate" to change the color

Answer (score 0):

you could recreate the pulsing effect you want using animate in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#white36').click(function() {
      $('#book').animate({
        background-color: 'red',
      }, 300).animate({
        background-color: 'white',
      }, 300).animate({
        background-color: 'red',
      }, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: but the pulsing isn't in that code so it doesn't pulsate

Comment: what's wrong with the code above is not the fact that there is no `.effect('pulsate'` but the fact that you can't animate background color and I wrongly thought you could. to achieve this you will need to use $.color() which can be found here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0):

for some ideas:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#white36").click(function () {
    $("#book").animate({ 
      width: "50%",
      opacity: 0.3,
      fontSize: "3em", 
      borderWidth: "10px",
      color: "black",
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 1500 );
  });
});
```

edit: just tried to run the above code and it didn't work when background-color was specified. If i ran it without that param it worked fine though. Guess it's buggy as I tried with both "background-color" and "backgroundColor"